# How to avoid numbering the bibliography at the end, and the partial bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

in my thesis i've two problems

1. In the bibliography for each chapter, the header has the same number of the previous section:

   [image]
2. is inserted into the chapter number in the bibliography. how can I do?

   [image]

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15269862/trys.rar) there are the MWE

Comment: I've moved the images from the links you've provided to the posting itself. However, I am unable to open the link you're providing to the MWE itself -- I'm not familiar with the file type .rar. Could you post a link to an ascii file?

Comment: To remove the chapter number in the global bibliography, change the option `bibliography=totocnumbered` to `bibliography=totoc` when loading `scrbook`

Comment: The number in chapter bibliographies is `titlesec` fault...

Comment: @karlkoeller with 'totoc' i've solved. but how i can modify 'titlesec'

Comment: Try to add for example `\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]{\usekomafont{section}}{}{.0em}{}`.

Comment: Otherwise `\newcommand\boxedsectionnull[1]{\boxedSectionB{#1}{\phantom{\thesection}}{2mm}}` and `\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]{\usekomafont{section}}{}{.0em}{\filright\boxedsectionnull}`

Comment: dropbox link is dead

Answer (score 4):

To remove the chapter number in the global bibliography, you have to change the option `bibliography=totocnumbered` to `bibliography=totoc` when loading `scrbook`.

Instead, the number in chapter bibliographies depends on the fact you changed the title format for numbered sections through `titleformat`, but not the format for unnumbered sections. To do that, you can either add the line

```
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]{\usekomafont{section}}{}{.0em}{}
```

or the lines

```
\newcommand\boxedsectionnull[1]{\boxedSectionB{#1}{\phantom{\thesection}}{2mm}}‌​
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]{\usekomafont{section}}{}{.0em}{\fi‌​lright\boxedsectionnull}
```

and the problem will be solved.